# linear algebra in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, floating-point, linear-algebra

Given a tall `m by n` matrix `X`, I need to calculate `s = 1 + x(X.T X)^{-1} x.T`. Here, `x` is a row vector and `s` is scalar. Is there an efficient (or, recommended) way to compute this in python?

Needless to say, `X.T X` will be symmetric positive definite.

My attempt:

If we consider the `QR` decomposition of `X`, i.e., `X = QR`, where `Q` is orthogonal, `R` is upper triangular, then `X.T X` = `R.T R`.

`QR` decomposition can be easily obtained using `numpy.linalg.qr`, that is

```
Q,R = numpy.linalg.qr(X)
```

But then again, is there a particularly efficient way to calculate `inv(R.T R)`?

Comment: What are you going to do with the inverse?  If you are going to multiply it by a known vector `x` (e.g. `y = inv(R.T.dot(R)).dot(x)`, it is more efficient and more numerically stable to instead write `y = np.linalg.solve(R.T.dot(R), x)`.

Comment: I needed it for the formula:   s = 1 + x * inv(R.T * (R)) * x.T  where, yes, x is a known vector.

Comment: I would recomend checking out this. http://www.python-course.eu/matrix_arithmetic.php

Comment: Is this known `x` vector a *row* or a *column* vector? I ask because if it’s a row vector, that implies `s` is scalar and `1` is a scalar too.

Comment: x is a row vector. So $x^t$ will be a column vector. s will be a scalar. What Warren Weckesser suggests is the way I will go about it. I am not able to upvote his answer for some reason and don't know how to mark it as 'accepted' either.

Comment: Yeah, @WarrenWeckesser post your comment as an answer, it’s a good one. Unless I’m very confident my square matrix is well-behaved, I try to avoid `np.linalg.solve` because it uses a LU solver (search [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) for `gesv`, which is LAPACK’s LU solver), and LU solvers often have accuracy problems. When runtime isn’t an issue, I like using `np.linalg.lstsq` because it uses SVD/pseudo-inverse, which is super-accurate.

Comment: Interestingly, R’s equivalent for solving a square linear system uses the QR decomposition, as QR solvers can be much faster than SVD with nearly as good accuracy. But I don’t know of a QR solver in Numpy/Scipy 

Comment: Yeah ... I have a tendency to avoid SVD until really needed. Especially right now I am going to have large matrices ... and runtime WILL be an issue. I would have preferred something based on QR decomposition. But I am not able to find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by efficient way? in case you mean speed up the running time, you have to calculate the cost of each of the NumPy function you are calling.Don't forget transforming your formula induce an additional time

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing the `QR` factorization of `X`, resulting in `X.T X = R.T R`, you may avoid using `np.linalg.inv` (and `np.linalg.solve`) by using forward and backward substitution instead (`R.T` is lower triangular!) with [`scipy.linalg.solve_triangular`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_triangular.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as LA
Q,R = np.linalg.qr(X)
# solve R.T R z = x such that R z = y 
# with step (a) then (b)
# step (a) solve  R.T y = x
y   = LA.solve_triangular(R,x,trans='T') 
# step (b) solve R z = y
z   = LA.solve_triangular(R,x)
s   = 1 + x @ z
```

where `@` is the `python3` matrix multiplication operator.